# PowerShell Open Close Browser Randomly

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

How Do I Open and close chrome browser randomly in an infinite loop basically I need a script to open 3 URLs on randomly the whole night.

```
$URLs = @(
'http://site.tld/url1'
'http://site.tld/url2'
'http://site.tld/url3'
)

$minSeconds = 10 * 60
$maxSeconds = 15 * 600

# Loop forever
while($true){
# Send requests to all 3 urls
$URLs |ForEach-Object {
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_
}

# Sleep for a random duration between 10 and 15 minutes
Start-Sleep -Seconds (Get-Random -Min $minSeconds -Max $maxSeconds)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke-* does not open a browser. You use those to interact with web site info without the need for a browser. You'd want to use Start-Process, which will open the default browser. You can of course instead start Chrome.

```
$URLs = @(
'http://site.tld/url1'
'http://site.tld/url2'
'http://site.tld/url3'
)

$minSeconds = 10 * 60
$maxSeconds = 15 * 600

# Loop forever
while($true)
{
    # Send requests to all 3 urls
    $URLs | ForEach-Object {Start-Process $PSitem}

    # Sleep for a random duration between 10 and 15 minutes
    Start-Sleep -Seconds (Get-Random -Min $minSeconds -Max $maxSeconds)
}
```

After that sleep line, you need to add code to close the browser.

```
$URLs | 
ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath chrome.exe -ArgumentList $PSitem}

Stop-Process -Name chrome -Force
```

Comment: what I need is when I start PowerShell a random URL should be open and close after 10 seconds. then auto-open browser on random time and close after 10 seconds

Comment: Why the consistent open can close the browser for each URL? A tab is a new browser instance. So, IMHO, yo open the browser once, to a blank landing page, then open a new tab with the target URL, close that tab after your time, then hit the next, and so on. Without the resource hit of opening and close the full browser, or is this that you need a fresh browser session for each URL? Yet, if you are not clearing cache, cookies, etc., what's the point, since all that will still be there when the browser is restarted.

Comment: As for this ...[after 10 seconds]... Tha that si to what your code says. You are using minutes, randomly, vs 10 seconds specifically as that would be only [Start-Sleep -Seconds 10], thus that whole min/max thing is moot.